# Subitem on mat-list

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm doing a menu page on Angular. What I want is to make a submenu in this screen. For example, an option with "Enviar mensaje", and when I press there, to have some options behind to go there.

[image: 1]

I did it with this code:

```
 <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
      <mat-nav-list>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/versolis'"> Visualizar solicitudes </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/enviarB2'"> Enviar mensaje B2 NNSS </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/enviarB2baja'"> Enviar mensaje B2 Baja </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/enviarB4'"> Enviar mensaje B4 NNSS </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/enviarB4baja'"> Enviar mensaje B4 Baja </a>
        <a mat-list-item (click)="sidenav.toggle()" href="" mat-list-item>Cerrar sesión</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
```

Could you help me to do it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add `mat-sidenav-content` and `mat-toolbar` for this to work. Here is how you can do this. Firstly add `mat-sidenav-content` which will place your content on the right side of the page. Then add `mat-toolbar` which will be the top menu bar used to open and close sidenav bar with a hamburger button.

For click event, you will add `sidenav.toggle()` which is material's own method for toggling the nav. Here `sidenav` is the reference variable defined on `mat-sidenav`

```
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div style="height: 88vh;">
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
          <button  mat-icon-button 
                   aria-label="Menu"
                   (click)="sidenav.open()">
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>  
  </mat-toolbar>
```

Once this is done, add it inside your `mat-sidenav` tag.

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>   //========> sidenav reference defined
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a *ngFor="let route of routes"
         mat-list-item  
         [routerLink]="route.path" 
         (click)="sidenav.toggle()"> {{route.label}}</a> //=====> use reference to toggle nav
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div style="height: 88vh;">
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
          <button  mat-icon-button 
                   aria-label="Menu"
                   (click)="sidenav.open()">
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>  
  </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-sidenav-generate-nav